# How do I remove the hostname from the bash prompt in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

My prompt in Terminal currently looks like:

```
Dzulhelmis-MacBook-Pro:~ myusername$
```

I want it to be as short as possible, maybe at least no hostname there. How do I change my bash prompt?